# Free memory for elements of GArray

Tags: c, linux, free, glib

I create `drvm *drv` structure in my function. This structure itself contains fields which contains `malloc()-ed` fields (`uint32_t *buffer`). The code which do that is similar to that:

```
...
size_t elm_size = sizeof(model*);
uint32_t length = *(uint32_t*)len;

GArray *models = g_array_sized_new(FALSE, FALSE, elm_size, length);

model *mod;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    mod = create_model(...);
    g_array_append_val(models, mod);
}
```

This piece of code doesn't contain errors and is highly tested.
At the start of program I register function `free_all()` (by `atexit()`) which should clean all resources (especially memory) when `exit()` is performed.

Inside this function I'm trying freeing memory of `elements of GArray*` (`model *` structure) **and** memory for `GArray *` itself:

```
GArray *models;
g_array_set_clear_func(models, clean_model);
if(!g_array_free(models, FALSE)) { //OK }
```

The problem is that when `clean_model(void *data)` is called inside `glib` library I suggest it contains pointer to one `model *` element. But the address is wrong, it doesn't seem point to any correct value.  Neither `GArray*`, nor `model*`.

Furthermore `GArray *models` in `free_all()` function is correct (the same as when I created it) and when I iterate through all `GArray *` elements in `free_all()` by

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    mod = g_array_index(models, model*, i); // Here I get correct pointer to model*
    clean_model(mod);
}
```

I get expected values.

**Question:** What's wrong? How should I free memory of elements of `GArray *` if these elements contain `malloc()-ed` memory?

**Part of header:**

```
struct _info {
    uint32_t *buffer;
    uint32_t len;
};

typedef struct _info info;

struct _prod {
    uint32_t *buffer;
    uint32_t len;
};

typedef struct _prod prod;

struct _model {
    uint32_t name;
    prod product;
    info inform;
};

typedef struct _model model;

struct _drvm {
    GArray *models;
    GArray *strings;
};

typedef struct _drvm drvm;
```

Comment: It seems to me that you should be using a [GPtrArray](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html), since you're storing pointers. What is `elm_size`? There seems to be confusion, here.

Comment: Maybe `GPtrArray*` is better. But why I get wrong pointer? In my opinion if glib call my `clean_model()` function it should pass `model *` element which I could correctly freeing inside `clean_model()` -  "If free_segment is `TRUE` it frees the memory block holding the elements as well and also each element if array has a `element_free_func` set"

Comment: Did you try to isolate your issue to a minimal example? I am in doubt this has to do anything with glib logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the problem is that your `clean_model` function is passed `model**` instead of `model*` you were expecting.

Remember that `GArray` is meant to store complete structs, not just pointers to structs. In order to do that it needs to *copy* the whole contents of the struct into the internal `data` array and therefore any subsequent pointers to the structs (as passed to `clean_model`) are going to be pointing somewhere inside `data` (i.e. `clean_model((elt_type*)&models->data[index * sizeof(elt_type)])` - where in your case `elt_type` is `model*`)

To fix the situation couple options come to mind, in order of (subjective) preference:

1. use `GPtrArray` instead; given that your elements are dynamically allocated already the memory management / pointer handling / typecasts (or lack thereof) would be less confusing
2. change `clean_model` argument to `model**`
3. use `GArray` to store `model` structs rather than pointers, but only makes sense if you can separate the allocation from populating the model contents, e.g. `g_array_new(FALSE, FALSE, sizeof(model))` and `fill_model(&g_array_index(models, model, i))`

In all cases you should also probably pass `TRUE` to `g_array_free` since you don't seem to be using the `GArray.data` for anything afterwards (not that it would make any sense given that you're freeing all the useful data in it anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I didn't check all variants as using GPtrArray solved my problem.